# External References to SQL tables in Visual Studio 2017 causes schema compare to not allow updates

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, external-tables

I have created a database project in the latest version of SSDT in visual studio 2017 (side note: please sort out your naming Microsoft as there are 2 products called SSDT!).

I have connected to an Azure SQL PaaS database, which works fine and downloads scripts for all tables etc all a-OK. Now, I have made a number of changes to the database within visual studio and I suspect a few changes have been made to the database by others (database drift). I have run a compare between the database project and the database to detect the changes, all good so far, there are quite a few changes that I wish to update.

However the "Update" button is disabled due to a number of errors. The errors are almost all due to Visual Studio not understanding the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE references in Azure SQL Server ("The external data source type RDBMS is not supported on the current platform"). There are also other errors to do with external tables "The ObjectName option is not supported on the current platform", "The SchemaName option is not supported on the current platform" etc etc.

The result is I cannot synch database projects to Azure SQL due to the errors. Seems Microsoft has really dropped the ball here by not supporting its own products properly. Any workarounds?

Comment: Have you set the properties of the project to azure v12?

Comment: Damn, looks like you are right Ed. I assumed that this would be set automatically when I pointed it to a SQL Azure server... obviously not. Now I have a hole host of other errors due to automatically creating these external tables on the fly. Hmmm... maybe I won't be able to do compares as easily as I thought.

Comment: I think if you do an import from a database it should set it correctly, if it doesn't maybe raise a connect?